# W3 Total Cache Help - How to update DNS Zone for a static domain

Tags: plugins, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache, cdn, static-website

I am running this site: www.thetechnofreaks.com on Wordpress. Recently I came through a plugin that claims to increase the page load efficiency of my site. the plugin details can be found here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/installation/

Now the plugin mentions a self-hosted method for CDN which is known as pipelining. It states:

> If you do not have a CDN provider, you can still improve your site's
>   performance using the "Self-hosted" method. On your own server, create
>   a subdomain and matching DNS Zone record; e.g. static.domain.com and
>   configure FTP options on the "Content Delivery Network" tab
>   accordingly. Be sure to FTP upload the appropriate files, using the
>   available upload buttons.

Now I have created a static.thetechnofreaks.com sub-domain but I don't know how to enter matching DNS Zone record and configure FTP options.

Please guide me in this regard. I went to my cPanel -> Simple DNS Zone Editor. It contains:

Add an A Record

Name:
Address:

Add a CNAME Record

Name:
CNAME:

What am I supposed to enter in this??

Answer (score 1):

If you have created your subdomain using Cpanel then you don't have to do anything in regards to changing DNS records, It's all done for your. As for creating an ftp account there is a nice tutorial at the [Cpanel docs section](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/FTPAccounts#Add%20an%20FTP%20Account).